# How to pass JSON value-key pairs into bash command

Tags: bash

I am having this issue that I want to read values from a json string in BASH and pass them on to a bash command. Basicly I want to transform e.g.:

```
{first: a, second: b} -> first=a second=b
{first: a, second: b, third: c} -> first=a second=b third=c
{1: a, 2:b} -> 1=a, 2=b
```

How would I do that so it will work no matter how many key-value pairs there are in the json string?

so far I have gotten this far:

```
a='{"first": "a", "second": "b"}'
echo ${a} | jq -r 'to_entries | .[] | .key + "=" + .value'
first=a
second=b
```

But I want it to be on the same line separated by " "

Comment: You're looking for `to_entries | map(.key+"="+.value) | join(" ")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tool called `jq` to pass the JSON into a command, and this would be encoded also if required, with many more features included.

More information can be found on the following link,
https://stedolan.github.io/jq/